# Is $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2 n}$ a convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried to evaluate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2 n}$$ to test whether it is a convergent series  using standard method like creterion test really I think that $ \sin^2 n$ Bounded sequence which is its multiplicative inverse multiplied by a convergent sequence , But my problem is about the Growth rate of :$\dfrac{1}{\sin^2 n}$ seems not clear to me , Now am not able to test the convergence of this series, anyway ?

Comment: It's expected to be convergent, but nobody knows at the moment. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is an exact duplicate, as noted by @GabrielRomon. The system will not allow us to close _as a duplicate_ because the previous question did not get an answer (probably because it's still an open problem), but that doesn't make it any less a duplicate.

Comment: I've flagged it for mod intervention as it is an exact duplicate and there's no hope for a way forward on this post beyond what was contained in the other linked.